# Decomposition of Laurent polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $H \in \mathbb{C}[z]$ be a polynomial of degree $d \geq 1$ and define $F(z) = \overline{H}(z^{-1}) \cdot H(z)$ where $\overline{H}$ is the polynomial $H$ with complex-conjugated coefficients. Apparently, one can then write $$F(z) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & z^{-1} & \cdots & z^{-d} \end{pmatrix} \cdot \overline{h} h^T \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ z \\ \vdots \\ z^d \end{pmatrix}$$ for some vector $h \in \mathbb{C}^{d+1}$. Why is this the case?

Comment: In your expression of $\;H(z)\;$ , what is the row vector? It isn't clear at all...

Comment: You mean $h$? It's the vector for which I am asking why it exists. The other row vector (1 z^{-1} ...  z^{-d}) is what it is.

Comment: Well, yes: *after* I wrote the comment you edited your question and now it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H(z) = h_0 + h_1z^1 + \dots + h_dz^d$, and $\overline{H}(z) = \overline{h_0} + \overline{h_1}z^1 + \dots + \overline{h_d}z^d$.

Then $h = (h_0 \ h_1 \ \dots \ h_d)$ is the row vector you're looking for.

I'm assuming that by $\cdot$ you mean the dot-product, and you mean to write that $F(z) = [\begin{pmatrix} 1 & z^{-1} & \cdots & z^{-d} \end{pmatrix} \cdot \overline{h}] [h^T \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ z \\ \vdots \\ z^d \end{pmatrix}]$

Note that $a b^T = a \cdot b$ if $a, b$ are row vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If $h^T=(h_0, h_1, \ldots, h_d)$ then $h^T$ times the last column vector $e(z)$ is nothing but $H(z)=h_0 + h_1 z + \cdots h_d z^d$. Similarly for the first row vector $e(z^{-1})^T$ times $\bar{h}$. Then:
$$F(z) =(e(z^{-1})^T \bar{h}) \ \  (h e(z))$$
is simply a product of two Laurent series. Matrix multiplication is associative, however, so you may write it the way you mention.